# Contradiction while taking determinant of a nilpotent matrix

Tags: matrices

Consider a nilpotent matrix $A$ of index of nilpotency $n$ , then $A^n=O$ and $A^{n-1}\neq O$ where $O$ denotes null matrix of same order as of $A$

Now $A^n=O\implies \det(A)^m=0\implies \det(A)=0$

but $A^{n-1}\neq O\implies \det(A)\neq0$

I know I am wrong in the second statement because a matrix not being equal to a null matrix doesn't imply that it has to be necessarily non-singular.

Therefore aren't we allowed to take determinant on both sides for the inequation $A\neq O$ ?

Comment: The question from the last sentence is answered be the previous sentence.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thankyou, i just wanted to confirm whether i am right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement $A^{n-1}\neq O\implies \det(A)\neq0$ is wrong. In other words, there can be non-zero matrices with zero determinants. For example, consider the matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}